# Default Value or Binding for an INT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using Microsoft SQL I want the default value to be 0 for the column.

Should the Default Value or Binding for an INT be (0) or ((0))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really is no different. Both sets of parentheses are ignored internally. You may use `(0)` when creating the constraint but, depending on the tool you use to create and the tool you're using to show it, you may see extra parens added "for you." I bet you come across this less if you use DDL to add constraints rather than specifying them in the visual designers. :-)